# UICollectionView is coming up blank

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to fill a UICollectionView with images from the PhotoLibrary but when I run the code the screen comes up blank. I am new to Swift so I am assuming my issue is something simple but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong or why it shows up blank. What am I doing wrong?

```
import UIKit
import Photos

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class ViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
        
    var imageArray = [UIImage]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        grabPhotos()
    }
    
    func grabPhotos(){
    
        let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()
        let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
        requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
        requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
        
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
        
        if let fetchResult : PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions){
            if fetchResult.count > 0 {
                for i in 0..<fetchResult.count{
                    imgManager.requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: i), targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {
                        image, error in
                        self.imageArray.append(image!)
                    })
                }
            } else {
                print("you do not have any photos")
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource
    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return imageArray.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
        imageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = collectionView.frame.width / 3 - 1
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1.0
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1.0
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not relevant but `requestOptions.isSynchronous = true` is illegal on the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this block of code:

```
    if let fetchResult : PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions){
        if fetchResult.count > 0 {
            for i in 0..<fetchResult.count{
                imgManager.requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: i), targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {
                    image, error in
                    self.imageArray.append(image!)
                })
            }
        } else {
            print("you do not have any photos")
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

You are saying:

*"If count is greater than zero, append the images to the array. Else, reload the collection view data."*

Add the reload line after you've updated your data array:

```
    if let fetchResult : PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions){
        if fetchResult.count > 0 {
            for i in 0..<fetchResult.count{
                imgManager.requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: i), targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {
                    image, error in
                    self.imageArray.append(image!)
                })
            }
            // make sure this is called on the main thread
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }
        } else {
            print("you do not have any photos")
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

---

**Edit** *in response to your comment...*

After reviewing your code a bit, you are doing many, many things wrong.

To start with, you are registering a default `UICollectionViewCell`, then trying to access a `UIImageView` in that cell with `cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView` --- which will never succeed.

Next, you are trying to return the number of photos loaded as the `numberOfSections` in the collection view, and then returning `0` (zero) as the `numberOfItemsInSection` for each section. So, even if you successfully load images, nothing will ever be displayed.

Third, loading the assets and getting images are asynchronous processes. You're not doing that correctly at all.

I ***strongly suggest*** that you first go through some tutorials on collection views and custom cells. Learn how that works first.

Then, go through some tutorials on loading images from the device.

Then, work on putting it all together.

Apple has a [sample app](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html) that demonstrates displaying assets in a thumbnail grid, that covers all of these tasks. It's out-of-date (Swift 3) so you would need to do some manual fixes to the code... but, in the process of making those fixes, you would likely learn a bit anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I see what you are saying, but it is still coming up blank. I added a print statement below the "DispatchQueue.main.async" line and got a printed message letting me know that the DispatchQueue had run and it gives me a count of the items that I have in the PhotoLibrary but it is still blank. I am not sure why. Any ideas?

Comment: thank you so much for this response! As you clearly picked up on, I am new to Swift (a few months). I was following some guides online and I thought they seemed “off” but I am too inexperienced to tell what specifically was wrong. You have helped me more than you know! Thanks for you help/guidance. It is greatly appreciated!